# How to get SELECT EXISTS() query value

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this php code:

```
$query = $database->query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = '$contactID')";

if($query == 0){
echo "not registered";
}elseif($query == 1){
echo "registered"
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the query is suppose to return 0 or 1 and it works in my SQLite manager. What is the correct way on getting that value in Php and use it in IF ELSE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a single value, you can use [querySingle](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.querysingle.php):

```
$result = $database->querySingle("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = '$contactID'");
```

Otherwise, with normal queries, the result returned by `->query` isn't actually the data itself, but an identifier you would use to get data from the database:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Syntactic Fructose